# Why does Kubernetes' "kubectl" abort with “Authorization error”?

Tags: authorization, kubernetes, kubectl

After having changed the IP configuration of the cluster (all *external* IPs changed, the internal private IPs remained the same), some `kubectl` commands do not work anymore for any container.  The pods are all up and running, and seem to find themselves without problems.  Here is the output:

```
bronger@penny:~$ time kubectl logs jb-plus--prod-615777041-71s09
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)

real    0m30,539s
user    0m0,441s
sys     0m0,021s
```

Apparently, there is a 30 seconds timeout, and after that the authorisation error.

What may cause this?

I run Kubernetes 1.8 with Weave Net.

Comment: most likely you new ip missing from the certficate. check with this command `openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -noout -text |grep DNS`

Comment: Yes, this was it (or the important part of the problem).  If you convert your posting to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: glad it helped let me update the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the symptom  new ip missing from the certificate. use the below command to validate.

```
 openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -noout -text |grep DNS
```

Comment: The timeout was due to outdated public IPs in various configuration files in `/etc/kubernetes`, and outdated public IPs in some pods from the kube-system namespace.  However, the authorization error itself was indeed due to the missing new IP in the certificate of the API server.